# Youtube says video is unavailable depending on router

Tags: networking, router, youtube

Occasionally, I received the following "error" from Youtube when I am connected to my TP link router. On the other hand, if I connect to the internet service provider's router directly, then I can play the video.

[image: Youtube error]

My preferred setup is `Internet <- ISP router <- TP link router <- laptop`. If I change this to `Internet <- ISP router <- laptop` everything works.

I checked the router settings to see if there are any parental control settings, but could not find anything.

The TP link router is:

- Firmware Version:‪1.3.0 0.9.1 v0001.0 Build 210208 Rel.61056n
- Hardware Version:‪Archer MR600 v2 00000001

Do you have any idea how could I get these restrictions lifted? I guess it should be some router setting.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the TP Link router?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the TP-Link router is restricting access to YouTube.  Go into the router's settings and check for restricted domains and/or services.  It might be easier to do a factory reset.  Check the manual on how to do that.

Did you get this router new-in-box?  Or was this used?